# "inputRef" while integrating third party libraries with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) in material ui shows an example on how to integrate the Input component with 3rd party libraries(react-text-mask in this case).

saw the below lines of code which I failed to understand

```
ref={ref => {
        inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
      }}
```

1. Why is the **inputRef** method invoked here?
2. What does **ref.inputElement** return?

Attaching the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5tb95)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputRef` is specified [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.0/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L322) and points at a function called `handleInputRef` in `InputBase`. This `handleInputRef` function takes care of setting InputBase's local [inputRef](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.0/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L194) with the value passed to it.

`MaskedInput` is a [class component](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/react-v5.4.3/react/src/reactTextMask.js#L7) so when you specify a `ref` on it, the `ref` that gets passed as the argument to the arrow function in the code in your question text will be the component instance. `ref.inputElement` is then the same as [this.inputElement](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/react-v5.4.3/react/src/reactTextMask.js#L17) within `MaskedInput` which points at the actual text input.

Overall this is just a mechanism for weaving the appropriate ref for the text input from `MaskedInput` to Material-UI's `InputBase` so that it can use the ref for [focus management](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.0/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L304).